# With Buildbot Source Step: why can 'codebase' not be set via Interpolate while 'repourl' can?

Tags: buildbot, codebase

I have a factory that I use in several builders and I set builder specific settings via `util.Property` and `util.Interpolate`. While this works fine for `repourl` and `branch` it simply doesn't work for `codebase`. The following piece of code shows the source step how I would like to use it in my Buildbot configuration.

```
factory.addStep(
    steps.Git(repourl=util.Interpolate('git://repo_base_path/%(prop:build_repository)s', default=''),
              branch=util.Property('build_branch', default='master'),
              mode='full',
              codebase=util.Interpolate('%(prop:build_repository)s', default=''),
              method='copy', submodules=True, clobberOnFailure=True)
    )
)
```

Without the codebase part all worked fine. I then figured I would need to set the codebase for some cases so I added the codebase line, resulting in the following error:

```
[-] Configuration Errors:
[-]   error while parsing config file: sequence item 1: expected
      string, Interpolate found traceback in logfile
```

Does anybody know why it is not possible to set the `codebase` via Interpolate while it is no problem to do the same thing with `repourl`?
Does somebody have an idea how to set the codebase for the source step to something different from '' and still not create a separate factory instance for every builder?

Any insights into this and any helpful suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: I thought the `Property` and `Interpolate` classes were in the `buildbot.process.properties` package, at least they seem to be in the various versions from the last few years.  How are you getting to them via `util`?

Comment: @doshea: It seems that steps and related stuff is now implemented as a plugin. The current documentation proposes to use `from builbot.plugins import steps, util` and then access steps via the `steps` namspace and e.g. `Properties` via util. So in this case util does not refer to `buildbot.utils` but to `buildbot.plugins.util`.Sorry that this information was missing in my question.

Comment: No need to apologize, I should have read the latest documentation better :)  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug in Buildbot.  Looking at the Buildbot 0.8.12 sources, I can see that in `buildbot/steps/source/git.py`, in `class Git`, the `renderables` attribute includes `"codebase"`, which should mean that you can use `Interpolate` in this way.  Presumably some other code is assuming it can interpret `codebase` as a string at the time the configuration is parsed.

In other words, as far as I can tell, you're doing something that the `Git` class claims to support.

It looks like the old-style Git support in `buildbot/steps/source/oldsource.py` doesn't support `codebase` being a renderable, but it doesn't look to me like you're using that.  I'm not entire sure, though, because I'm not sure what `steps.Git` refers to.

Comment: Thank's for looking that up. I think I will file a bug report then. Btw. `steps.Git` refers to buildbot.plugins.steps and that's where the new style steps recide now (they're still accesible via `buildbot.steps.source`, but as far as I undestand they may not in the future). I wanted to vote your answer up, but I can't because I do not have enough reputation yet ...